# Ubuntu stuck after log in

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on Vmware.

After I put my password to log in, It just stuck like the screenshot below.

Any suggestions? or something to reference?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: ram available to  guest (the ubuntu vm)?  graphics card?  (again to the vm)  --can the  host OS  support  these settings ?

Comment: @linuxdev2013 vm settings might not a problem. I used it until yesterday, I think some updates cause this problem.

Comment: No screenshot below. Can you access one of the consoles? Host key + F1, the Host key is normally the right control key.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes, I can access the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access the console, then you have a problem with Xorg or your window manager (lightdm? gdm? kdm?...). Login, then from the console stop the graphic session,

```
  sudo service lightdm stop
```

(please correct for your WM). Now you have to troubleshoot the local problem. First, make a full system upgrade and reboot. Again from the console,  start the WM and see which, if any, errors are reported.

```
  sudo service lightdm start
```

Alternatively look up the /var/log/Xorg.0.log* file, and see whether any error is reported. You can take it from here.

Comment: I found an error in /var/log/Xorg.0.log file. "(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)". Cuda toolkit, I installed caused a problem. I uninstalled it and can log in successfully.

Comment: @enc What exactly did you uninstall and how? can you write an answer? I have same exact problem on 16.04.3 LTS.

Comment: @Shayan Removing cuda toolkit helped as I mentioned above. [this](https://davidstutz.de/upgrading-cuda-and-installing-cudnn-for-caffe-and-tensorflow/) may help.

Comment: `which nvcc` returns nothing so I guess I don't have it installed!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here after fresh install of Ubuntu 14 (i386).iso on VMware 9 (32bit) on Windows 7 (32bit).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>  should go back to a non-windowed console.

```
login <qwerty keyboard>
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo service lightdm start
```

Resolved the problem. Note that if you are not in full screen with VMware, maybe you won't see the 'activities' menu.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned answers are correct. But I would like to give you a detailed answer

for Ubuntu 16 & above

1. Restart your computer & go to the Login screen.
   Do not enter any credentials.
2. Press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F2` to go to Emergency console screen and Enter your username & password
3. Then enter on of the commands depending on the Ubuntu version you are using

`sudo systemctl restart gdm.service` for default ubuntu

`sudo systemctl restart sddm.service` for Kubuntu & Lubuntu

`sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service` for Xubuntu, Ubuntu Mate & Ubuntu budgie

Reference:
https://superuser.com/a/1700847/1661620