# Ubuntu is not responding after login (20.04; Focal Fossa)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, login, xubuntu, lubuntu

An Ubuntu machine will be stuck on a "blank" screen after entering the user name and password in the login screen.

The login window is getting stuck after you enter the login credentials.

You will get some screen shown like below.

[image: Blank screen (orange)]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: But the screen shows 14.04(?).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried a lot of online solutions for this and finally found a proper solution.

We have to reset the login screen. By doing this, we will kill the current existing login session.

To do this,

1. Restart your computer and go to the login screen.
2. Do not enter any credentials.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to go to an emergency console screen.
4. Enter your username and password
5. Then enter the command `sudo systemctl restart gdm.service` (for [GDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Display_Manager))

This command works only for the default Ubuntu version.

For [Kubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu) and [Lubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) they use the [SDDM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Desktop_Display_Manager) login manager, so we have to enter `sudo systemctl restart sddm.service`

For [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu), Ubuntu [MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE), and Ubuntu [Budgie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budgie_(desktop_environment)), use `sudo systemctl restart lightdm.service`.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Huge thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me :

I tried the ubuntu recovery mode in advanced options for ubuntu , then i choose normal boot in it (i could not see it first ,then i pressed escape to see it). After that ubuntu boot up normally , but using a basic display adapter (just like windows safe mode). This time i was able to login ,I saw for some commands to fix broken packages and ran them , then i went to additional drivers application and installed my nvidia driver (latest and tested one) . Then i boot normal ubuntu and it Worked!

Im a newbie so i really dont know how it works , but if anyone has same issue can give a try